# Cannot convert null to 'float' because it is a non-nullable value type

Tags: html, razor

Can someone tell me what is wrong there? Because it throw error "Cannot convert null to 'float' because it is a non-nullable value type"

```
@model float

<div class="progress-bar">
<div class="progress-green-bar" style="width: @string.Format("{0}", (int?)(Model / 100.0f * 400));">
</div>
<div class="progress-bar-percent-text" style="text-align: center; color: black; font-size: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
    @((int?)(Model))%
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL means that there is no variable at all so You can not convert something what doeasn't exist. There is nothing what can be converted.

Comment: When i debug Model == 0, not null

Comment: But You used `int?` which means You allowed to variable to be nulltype. Make clear declaration - set for example "0."